# Configuration missing in magento2.3.5p2 admin panel

Tags: magento2.3, admin, configuration, magento-2-commerce

I recently downgraded magento commerce from 2.4 to 2.3.5p2 due to having some known issue, but after the change my

`Stores > Settings > Configuration`

appear only below config

[image]

it should not appear as the image above but instead as below

[image]

I have disabled elasticsearch

I have run necessary command to install

- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento setup:dicompile
- bin/magento indexer:reindex
- bin/magento cache:clean

I have give necessary read, write, execute access

I have run composer install and update

I have check on the user role and currently its been given Administrator role, so I expect it to gain full privileges

I already check on log but there is no error appear when the admin configuration page is being accessed

Please advice or guide ways that I can check and solve this problem

Comment: Do you have anything in Browser console? And meanwhile rename your app/code folder to remove all the custom code and see. Other things in admin and fronted working fine?

Comment: Please provide a way (code, etc) how you try to add image above

Comment: Hi @VictorTihonchuk the first image appear on magento commerce, the second image is from magento community, when trying to change from magento community to magento commerce suddenly the configuration appear only like the first image

Comment: Hi @JohnFonseka seems like other things in admin and frontend is working fine, just the configuration is missing in admin, I have tried disabling all added module through app/etc/config.php and surprisngly the configuration field finally appear in admin panel, it must be one of the module causing this issue but I am not sure how to track which module is causing this issue

Comment: Hi, I have able to fix the issue, turns out one of the module is causing an issue, I have tried try an error disabling 1 by 1 and a custom module is causing the error, have fixed an error inside the custom module which is caused by redundant layout file , now its okay

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I found the ShipStation integration by Auctane is the problematic module but I have no idea how to fix it. Can you please provide more specific details on how to fix it?

Comment: You would need to go to app/etc/config.php  path and remove the said module, I assume your module name is Auctane_ShipStation, set it to 0, if still unable to , rename the entire folder of that module and run all necessary command ( upgrade, compile, clear cache )